# How to return a sign up page with the correct radio button checked?

Tags: php, javascript, html

So I'm building a website that has a prices page in it that lists different subscription packages.  Each package option has a 'Sign Up' button under it that takes the user to my sign up page and on my sign up page there is a radio button group with each subscription option having its own radio button.  My question is, how can I return the sign up page with a specific radio button checked depending on which button was clicked on the price page?

I know I could have separate sign up pages, one for each option and have the specific radio button checked in the html but that seems really inelegant and I'm sure there is a better way to do this, either via a php response or maybe javascript??  Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use several options :

url : `http://example.com/signup?option1=true` 
sessions : `$_SESSION[signup1] = true/false` 
or via cookie

and set it up like that :

```
<input type="radio" <?php $_GET['option1'] ? "checked" : "" ?>
```

or

```
<input type="radio" <?php $_SESSION['option1'] ? "checked" : "" ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I kinda figured the solution had to do with passing data to the sign up page but didn't know how to get the btns to be checked.  I couldn't get your ternary method to work but I used 
`<input type="radio" name="subType" id="oneTour" value="oneTour" <?php $btn = $_GET['option1']; if($btn){echo 'checked';} ?>/>` 
and that works great.  Thanks again for the help!

Comment: guess I forgot echo sentence^^, just typed it not tested <?php $_GET['option1'] ? echo "checked" : "" ?> if it works don't forgot accept answer for other readers ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass data to the next page using get/post variables where each sign up button has its own form or you can set a cookie depending on which button is clicked. You can process the input on the next page and check the appropriate radio button.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways to do it.

Once user check that radio button
useing javascript:
1.you can set value to one html hidden element and post that form on the action page where you need to show sign up form

2.On radio button click check that if it is checked and then pass using javascript window.location you can pass that variable value using like http://www.asb.com?key=value

on the action page check for that which value has been set for that you can use

```
$value = $_REQUEST['key'];
switch($value) 
case 'price_1':
// do ur action here for price 1
// i.e set radio button
break;
case 'price_2':
// do your action here 
// i.e set other radio button
break;
```

condition, and you can decide what to perform in that case.

Hope this will work for your problem